# I can't find ServiceResourceId field when i try to insert it in validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, validation

I wanted to input  the ServiceResourceId lookup field in the validation rule on Service Crew Member but I can't find such a field in the insert section. When I tried write it I got error 'Error: Field ServiceResourceId does not exist. Check spelling.'  [image]